# Update table based on ColumnName of another table in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, toad

I have below data in Toad SQL Database table. Let us say the table name to be tblSample.

```
ID     NAME   COVERMONTH  EFFECTIVEDATE  TERMDATE  PAIDAMOUNT  EARNEDAMOUNT
1546871 SAMPLE1    202001   1-Aug-14     31-Dec-99       5122.12     5111.02  
1065418 SAMPLE2    202001   1-Jan-15     31-Dec-99           0           0
1546871 SAMPLE1    202002   1-Aug-14     31-Dec-99        5122.12     5111.02  
1065418 SAMPLE2    202002   1-Jan-15     31-Dec-99        3211.21     3211.21
1546822 SAMPLE3    202001   1-Jan-15     31-Dec-99        5122.12     5111.02  
1546822 SAMPLE3    202002   1-Jan-15     31-Dec-99        3211.21     3211.21
```

The number of ID's will be dynamic. I have modified the above table to the once as shown below as per the requirement. Got the result to a temptable.

```
 ID     NAME      EFFECTIVEDATE    TERMDATE    202001    202002   202003 ----- 201803
1546871 SAMPLE1   1-Aug-14      31-Dec-99  
1065418 SAMPLE2   1-Jan-15      31-Dec-99     
1546822 SAMPLE3   1-Jan-15      31-Dec-99
```

I have to update this temp table with PAIDAMOUNT

```
ID    NAME    EFFECTIVEDATE    TERMDATE    202001    202002   202003 --- -------- 201803
1546871 SAMPLE1   1-Aug-14      31-Dec-99  5122.12   5111.02   ------ ------
1065418 SAMPLE2   1-Jan-15      31-Dec-99      0     3211.21   ------ ------
1065418 SAMPLE3   1-Jan-15      31-Dec-99  5122.12   3211.21   ------ ------
```

I have to update the temptable based on ID and COVERMONTH in where condition, but the COVERMONTH are columnsin temptable.

Below is my query

```
DECLARE @ID varchar(50)
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR
LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT ID FROM temptable

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0

BEGIN
DECLARE @Counter1 int
SET @Counter1 = 1
DECLARE @FinalCounter int
SET @FinalCounter = (Select Count(*) FROM sampletable)
DECLARE @CoverMonth varchar(20)
DECLARE @UpdateSql1 varchar(200)

WHILE (@Counter1 <= @FinalCounter)
BEGIN
SET @CoverMonth = (SELECT COVERMONTH FROM sampletable where ID=@Id)
SET @UpdateSql1 = 'UPDATE temptable' + ' SET [' + @CoverMonth + ' ' = 'PAIDAMOUNT' WHERE ID=@Id and @CoverMonth= 'column name of temptable'.

EXEC(@UpdateSql1)
SET @Counter1=@Counter1+1
END
END
```

I could not complete the query. But came with an idea that 
Step1-> Iterate over the sampletable
Step2-> Iterate over the temptable
Step3-> Update query with sampletable.ID=temptable.ID and sampletable.COVERMONTH=temptable.[ColumnName]

How can I iterate over the COVERMONTH in sampletable to get all the covermonths for a particular ID and update the values

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't simply use a PIVOT? Try this:

```
    SELECT [ID], [NAME], [EFFECTIVEDATE], [TERMDATE], [202001], [202002]
    FROM (
        SELECT [ID], [NAME], [COVERMONTH], [EFFECTIVEDATE], [TERMDATE], [PAIDAMOUNT]
        FROM dbo.tblSample
    ) A
    PIVOT (
        SUM([PAIDAMOUNT])
        FOR [COVERMONTH] IN ([202001], [202002])
    ) B
```

PS: little hint.. forget Cursors!!

Comment: I can't use PIVOT since my COVERMONTH are dynamic. they change every month, so cannot hard code those values. The reason I have used CURSOR.

Answer (score 0):

and what about this?

```
    DECLARE @covermonths NVARCHAR(100) = (
        SELECT CONCAT(', [', [COVERMONTH], ']')
        FROM dbo.tblSample
        GROUP BY [COVERMONTH]
        FOR XML PATH('')
    );

    SET @covermonths = SUBSTRING(@covermonths, 2, LEN(@covermonths));

    DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(4000) = CONCAT(N'
        SELECT [ID], [NAME], [EFFECTIVEDATE], [TERMDATE], ', @covermonths, N'
        FROM (
            SELECT [ID], [NAME], [COVERMONTH], [EFFECTIVEDATE], [TERMDATE], [PAIDAMOUNT]
            FROM dbo.tblSample
        ) A
        PIVOT (
            SUM([PAIDAMOUNT])
            FOR [COVERMONTH] IN (', @covermonths, N')
        ) B
    ');

    EXEC (@statement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Above query did not work for me. 
Let me explain in other way
Update temptable SET '202001'='5122.12', '202002'='5111.02' where ID=1546871
Update temptable SET '202001'='0', '202002'='3211.21' where ID=1065418
'202001','202002' are columnname's in temptable and '5122.12', '5111.02'  are row value in tblSample with ID=1546871. and 202002 are also row value in tblSample for ID=1546871
I don't need SUM of these values. I need to make my temp table updated with EARNAMOUNT as explained in above update statement.
My result table is shown in my question

Comment: My update should happen dynamically is what I am looking for.